# Customized code in woocommerce empty cart message won't change in theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was trying to modify the empty cart message in woocommerce code, but when I make any change nothing happens in the theme (website)!

```
<div class="empt-container-cta">
    <a class="btn" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>">
                         <?php esc_html_e('your cart is empty Go Shopping') ?> <i class="ion ion-right ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this below code in active theme functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'wc_empty_cart_message', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'my_custom_empty_cart_message', 10 );
function my_custom_empty_cart_message() {
    $html = '<a class="btn" href="'.esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ).'">';
        $html .= esc_html_e('your cart is empty Go Shopping').'<i class="ion ion-right ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i>';
    $html .= '</a>';
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i added it but Unfortunately nothing changed! any solution ?